# Coursera Jupyter notebook trouble saving getting Forbidden

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, coursera-api

I am trying to submit an assignment in Coursera related to machine learning, but when  I am unable to save the notebook in the embedded jupyter notebook and seeing forbidden, don't know what's wrong, I tried to raise the complaint to coursera support but haven't heard back from them, its been 3days and i don't want to loose the traction of it. please help me resolve the issue

[image: screenshot highlighted with forbiden and autosave failed text]

Comment: You may need to enable cookies in your browser.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

seems like clearing enabling cookies explicitely for the site and changing the timezone did the magic, i am running inside a VPN so most of the time my clock is messed up, may be that could be the issue